# What is the word for judging someone blindly?

Tags: single-word-requests

Judging blindly- making assumptions or conclusions about a person without knowing them. This is usually based off stereotypes or other such things.

I'm looking for a synonym for this or what you would call someone who does this.

Examples in a sentence:

- "So you're obsessed with rocks," Mary judged blindly.
- Judging others blindly can/will lead to injustice.
- You have only known him 5 minutes, yet you are already blindly judging him.

Judging blindly or blindly judging sounds awkward in a lot of sentences. It can also get repetitive. This is why I would like to know a synonym for it.

Answer (score 3):

> Judging blindly- making assumptions or conclusions about a person without knowing them

Doing something [blindly](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/blindly) means *to do something without having enough information*. To *judge blindly* implies that you judge someone without having enough information.

***Prejudging*** is probably what you're looking for.

*Prejudging* means to judge someone/something before knowing or having enough information (the prefix *pre-* also indicates that).

[**Cambridge English dictionary**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/prejudge) defines it as:

> to form an opinion about a situation or a person before knowing or considering all of the facts:

In your example,

> "So you're obsessed with rocks," Mary judged blindly.

Presumably, Mary made that statement without having enough information, so you could say:

> "So you're obsessed with rocks", Mary prejudged them.

---

Here's a recent example from [**Fox8**](https://fox8.com/news/white-woman-charged-with-assault-of-black-girl-she-believed-was-stealing-her-mail/):

> “On the heels of the Ahmaud Arbery tragedy, there aren’t any good reasons for an adult to prejudge an 11-year-old girl, wrongly accuse her of a crime and then assault her as she picked up her grandmother’s mail.”

Compare it with your example:

> *Prejudging/prejudgment* can/will lead to injustice.

---

In your third example, you could replace 'blindly judging' with *prejudging*.

> You have only known him 5 minutes, yet you are already blindly judging him.

A has known B for 5 minutes and is making up something about B without having enough information, you could say *A is prejudging B*.

Here's a good example from [OregonLive](https://www.oregonlive.com/advice/2019/08/horoscope-for-aug-9-2019-aries-really-get-to-know-someone-pisces-hit-the-reset-button.html):

> ARIES (Mar 21-Apr. 19): Get to know someone. Shooting the breeze or traveling with a new acquaintance will allow you to find out more about what makes them tick. This knowledge is more valuable than prejudging others solely for their appearance.

Someone who prejudges could be described as *[prejudger](https://www.lexico.com/definition/prejudger)*.

If someone judges unfairly, you could say they're *[misjudging](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/misjudge)*.

You could also use *[presumption](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/presumption) (noun)*.

Comment: Can you edit this and give any justifications why you think this word applies to the original request? Copy-paste answers aren't a very good fit here. SE looks for original content (which of course might be supplemented with quotes of other sources).